# new vs make when creating channel

Tags: go, channel

In Go, I read document and understand basic differences between `make` and `new`

- new: return a pointer (*T) and zeros value it points to
- make: return type T

I read document and mostly example using array. I understand `new` vs `make` when creating array. But I don't understand differences when creating channel:

```
c1 := new(chan string)
c2 := make(chan string)
```

What is real differences except that c1 has type (chan*) and c2 has type chan.

Thanks

Comment: @Flimzy I have searched that post before but I cannot map that concept to "channel". So I asked this question.

Comment: That question directly and clearly addresses the question of channels. If you didn't "map" that concept, it means you didn't read the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of `new` is explained in [Allocation with `new`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new).

> It's a built-in function that allocates memory, but unlike its namesakes in some other languages it does not *initialize* the memory, it only *zeros* it.

In this case `new(chan string)` returns a pointer to a zero value of type `chan string`, which is the nil channel. The following program deadlock as it tries to read from a nil channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c1 := new(chan string)
    fmt.Println(*c1)
    go func() {
        *c1 <- "s"
    }()
    fmt.Println(<-*c1)
}
```

With `make(chan string)` you get an actual usable channel, not a zero value of channel type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c2 := make(chan string)
    fmt.Println(c2)
    go func() {
        c2 <- "s"
    }()
    fmt.Println(<-c2)
}
```